# An undefined method error, though pretty sure I did

Tags: ruby

```
`update': undefined method `hit_zom?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

        if @zombie.hit_zom?(bullet)\r
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

I have defined the `hit_zom` method in my Zombie class:

```
def hit_zom?(bullet)
          bullet.box && [[bullet.box.x1, bullet.box.y1], [bullet.box.x2, bullet.box.y2],
          [bullet.box.x3, bullet.box.y3], [bullet.box.x4, bullet.box.y4]].any? do |coordinates|
          @box.contains?(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
                                                                               end
        end
```

to call it in the `update` screen:

```
    if @zombie.hit_zom?(bullet)
          puts "sang noob"
        end
```

However, the aforementioned error occurred, I have been thinking about the problem for a while but I have yet to figure out a solution. I would be grateful if someone could help me
############################################################################
update: I have fixed the error thanks to the suggestion of sir Stefan from the comment section and here is the answer. I hope someone find this useful in the future:
full update method:

```
 def update
       
        if Window.frames % 360 == 0
            @zombie = Zombie.new
            @horde << @zombie 
            @zombie.reanimate
        if @zombie.hit_zom?(bullet)
            puts "sang noob"
        end
        end
        @horde.each { |zombie| zombie.move }
    end
```

the `hit_zom` condition was outside of the `Window.frame` condition , thus, @zombie was nill leading to the problem. Hope this helps

Comment: `@zombie` is set to nil. You need to check where `@zombie` is getting initialized and if it is being passed correctly

Comment: The error message says: _"undefined method \`hit_zom?' for **nil:NilClass**"_ which means that `@zombie` is not an instance of `Zombie` class (as you assumed) but an instance of [`NilClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/NilClass.html), i.e. `nil`.

Comment: @Kar98k can you [edit] your question and add the whole "update" code, i.e. including the initialization of `@zombie` and the `hit_zom?` call? (the implementation of `hit_zom?` on the other hand isn't relevant to the problem because it is not even called)

Comment: Many thanks, sir @Stefan, I have fixed the error thanks to your suggestion.It is as you have suspected, the condition method is outside of the method I called the zombie instance from Zombie class.

Comment: @Kar98k nice you figured it out! You might want to post your method's code anyway so someone can contribute an answer. (it's also perfectly fine to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own question or to simply [delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question))